# Print Local Group Members in PowerShell 5.0

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-10, adsi, powershell-5.0

I use the following code to determine members of the local Administrators group:

```
$obj_group = [ADSI]"WinNT://localhost/Administrators,group"
$members=@($obj_group.Invoke("Members"))|foreach{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name","GetProperty",$null,$_,$null)}
Write-Output "Current local Administrators: $members"
```

This code works in PowerShell 2.0 - 4.0.  However, on my Windows 10 machine with PowerShell 5.0, it breaks.  For each ***local*** account that is a member of the local Administrators group, it throws the following error:

```
Error while invoking GetType. Could not find member.
At line:2 char:54
+ ... "))|foreach{$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name","GetProperty",$null,$_,$ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], MissingMemberException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.MissingMemberException
```

For domain accounts that are a member of Administrators, no error is generated.

The thing that puzzles me is `GetType()` is a member of of the object (I traced out the command by hand), so I am not sure why it errors out.

I looked at the changelog for PowerShell 5.0 and did not see anything that would obviously explain this behavior.

Why is this happening?  If there a better way to print members of a local group in PowerShell 5.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ran into this issue myself and figured out a workaround (tested in windows 10 and 8.1)

```
$obj_group = [ADSI]"WinNT://localhost/Administrators,group"
$members= @($obj_group.psbase.Invoke("Members")) | foreach{([ADSI]$_).InvokeGet("Name")}
Write-Output "Current local Administrators: $members"
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Tested in XP (PowerShell 2.0), Windows 7 (PowerShell 4.0), and Windows 10 (PowerShell 5.0).

Answer (score 5):

Jamie's answer was perfect for your specific issue, but I have a need to get multiple properties from the members.  I found you can address this issue without otherwise changing your code by calling `Invoke` against `GetType` before calling `InvokeMember` against it.  Note that GetType no longer has `()` after it in the code below:

```
$obj_group = [ADSI]"WinNT://localhost/Administrators,group"
$members=@($obj_group.Invoke("Members"))|foreach{$_.GetType.Invoke().InvokeMember("Name","GetProperty",$null,$_,$null)}
Write-Output "Current local Administrators: $members"
```

This was my use case which provides more information about the group members.  This does require PowerShell 4.0 due to the use of the Resolve-DNS command:

```
function Get-LocalGroupMembers {
<#
.Synopsis
   Get the group membership of a local group on the local or a remote computer
.EXAMPLE
   Defaults to collecting the members of the local Administrators group

    PS C:\> Get-LocalGroupMembers | ft -AutoSize

    ComputerName ParentGroup Nesting Name          Domain       Class
    ------------ ----------- ------- ----          ------       -----
    EricsComputer                   0 Administrator EricsComp    User 
    EricsComputer                   0 eric          EricsComp    User 
    EricsComputer                   0 Domain Admins DomainName   Group
.EXAMPLE
   Query a remote computer (that is known not to respond to a ping) and a targeted group

    PS C:\> Get-LocalGroupMembers -computerName EricsComputer -localgroupName Users -pingToEstablishUpDown $false

    ComputerName ParentGroup Nesting Name          Domain       Class
    ------------ ----------- ------- ----          ------       -----
    EricsComputer                   0 SomeOtherGuy  EricsComp    User 

.NOTES
   The ParentGroup and Nesting attributes in the output are present to allow
   the output of this function to be combined with the output of 
   Get-ADNestedGroupMembers.  They serve no purpose otherwise.
#>
    Param(
        $computerName = $env:computername,
        $localgroupName = "Administrators",
        $pingToEstablishUpDown = $true
    )
    $requestedComputerName = $computerName
    if ($computername = Resolve-DnsName $computername) {
        $computername = ($computername | where querytype -eq A).Name
        if ($computername -ne $requestedComputerName) {
            Write-Warning "Using name $computerName for $requestedComputerName"
        }
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Unable to resolve $requestedComputerName in DNS"
        return "" | select @{label="ComputerName";Expression={$requestedComputerName}},
                                        @{label="ParentGroup";Expression={""}},
                                        @{label="Nesting";Expression={""}},
                                        @{Label="Name";Expression={"ComputerName did not resolve in DNS"}},
                                        @{Label="Domain";Expression={"ComputerName did not resolve in DNS"}},
                                        @{Label="Class";Expression={"ComputerName did not resolve in DNS"}}
    }
    if ($pingToEstablishUpDown) {
        if (-not (Test-Connection -count 1 $computerName)) {
            Write-Warning "Unable to ping $computerName, aborting ADSI connection attempt"
            return "" | select @{label="ComputerName";Expression={$requestedComputerName}},
                                        @{label="ParentGroup";Expression={""}},
                                        @{label="Nesting";Expression={""}},
                                        @{Label="Name";Expression={"Not available to query"}},
                                        @{Label="Domain";Expression={"Not available to query"}},
                                        @{Label="Class";Expression={"Not available to query"}}
        }
    }
    try {
        if([ADSI]::Exists("WinNT://$computerName/$localGroupName,group")) {    
            $group = [ADSI]("WinNT://$computerName/$localGroupName,group")  
            $members = @()  
            $Group.Members() | foreach {
                $AdsPath = $_.GetType.Invoke().InvokeMember("Adspath", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
                # Domain members will have an ADSPath like WinNT://DomainName/UserName.  
                # Local accounts will have a value like WinNT://DomainName/ComputerName/UserName.  
                $a = $AdsPath.split('/',[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
                $name = $a[-1]  
                $domain = $a[-2]  
                $class = $_.GetType.Invoke().InvokeMember("Class", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)  

                $members += "" | select @{label="ComputerName";Expression={$computerName}},
                                        @{label="ParentGroup";Expression={""}},
                                        @{label="Nesting";Expression={0}},
                                        @{Label="Name";Expression={$name}},
                                        @{Label="Domain";Expression={$domain}},
                                        @{Label="Class";Expression={$class}}
            }    
        }  
        else {  
            Write-Warning "Local group '$localGroupName' doesn't exist on computer '$computerName'"  
        }
    }
    catch { 
        Write-Warning "Unable to connect to computer $computerName with ADSI"
        return $false }
    return ,$members
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Nice! Needed this!

The .net way was also a [bypass](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/10/27/the-admins-first-steps-local-group-membership/):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$ctype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine
$computer =  $env:COMPUTERNAME
$context = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList $ctype, $computer
$idtype = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::SamAccountName
$group = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, $idtype, 'Administrators')
$group.Members |  select @{N='Server'; E={$computer}}, @{N='Domain'; E={$_.Context.Name}}, samaccountName
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me on a AzureAD joined computer

Answer (score 1):

You may want to post the bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell) as someone might have a workaround available.

Comment: It was already posted: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1437366/powershell-5-bug-in-gettype-for-com-objects-iadsuser

Answer (score 0):

I found you could also resolve this by replacing $_.GetType() with the underlying [System.__ComObject] type:

```
$obj_group = [ADSI]"WinNT://localhost/Administrators,group"
$members=@($obj_group.Invoke("Members"))|foreach{[System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("Name","GetProperty",$null,$_,$null)}
Write-Output "Current local Administrators: $members"
```

Hope this helps